# How to stop command prompt from blinking when opening batch file with console app c#?

Tags: c#, batch-file, exe

I need to execute a batch script from a console app written in c#. Using the code below my code does work, but fails to completely stay silent. When I say silent, I don't even want the CMD window to blink for a second.

**I have been using everyone else's suggestions from the site:**

```
        processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
```

None of which have been working.

**What I have so far:**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\test1.bat");
            processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            Process batchProcess = new Process();

            batchProcess.StartInfo = processInfo;

            batchProcess.Start();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say [UseShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_UseShellExecute) should be set to false judging from the docs.

Comment: What is the point of using `shellexeciute`?

Comment: Try `processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false; `

Comment: @Noodles I saw someone else using it saying that it prevents the window if you include createNoWindow = true...that didn't help

Comment: @shadoe2020 I have already tried that..same exact result

Comment: I'm assuming most of these other people asking similar questions just care that the window doesn't stay open, but don't mind the blink...I can't have the window blink, I need it to not appear entirely.

Comment: ShellExecute say execute my command in a **non standard** way. Shellexecute is like typing in the Start - Run dialog box.

Comment: To use the ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden you have to have UseShellExecute set to false. Try again? `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2`

Comment: I can tell you how to do it with vbs, maybe you can just call the vbs?

Comment: @shadoe2020 The purpose of all this is to create an exe that can call the batch script I have. Is it possible to call the vbs from the C# console, that calls the batch?

Comment: I don't have to use a C# console application, I just need to use Visual Studio to compile something into an exe that triggers a batch file.

Comment: C# can start programs the exact same way VBS can.

Comment: Don't compile as a console program.

Comment: @Noodles Are suggesting using the same code, but compile as a different kind of C# program?

Comment: C# and VBScript have access to all the system COM objects. You are using .NET objects. **BUT** You are compiling as a console program - console programs automatically get a console when they start. GUI programs get nothing when they start (they have to create any UI they want). So compile as `winexe` not `exe` so no console is created. Then lose the `useshellexecute`.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creation-of-a-console. If not using shellexecute your process object is a wrapper around `CreateProcess` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw and if using shellexecute a wrapper around `shellexecuteex` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexa (which after processing calls `CreateProcess`)